# How can we use Bluetooth communication (BLE protocol) on Android 10 (API 29) when the device hardware doesn't have hardware to provide the location

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I was developing a mobile App using Xamarin and a BLE package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BLE/) to communicate with a Bluetooth device using the Bluetooth low energy protocol.
When using the API 29 (Android 9) we need to have the location active. The documentation considers that and so far everything is working in some devices.
The problem is that some devices that are using the mobile App don't have a GPS antenna and when the users activate the location toggle in the operating system, the app doesn't assume that is turned on. If we ignore this requirement we simply can't scan for BT devices around.
Most likely, this is a common situation when developing this with Xamarin, Kotlin, etc.
Has anyone had this problem in the past?
Thank you all.

Comment: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues/581

Comment: Just out of interest: What are these devices without GPS antenna?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting when you turn the location on? The reason I ask is because turning the "location on" is an OS thing, so by toggling the switch, the OS should think that the location is on and therefore the BLE app should work fine.

Comment: @Jason, thanks for your feedback but having the permission required is not a problem. The issue is the need to have the location turned on during the BT usage.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKotzjan. The device is a Zebra. TC series. I'm thinking that they might have some responsibility on this since the OS is not getting the right info from hardware

Comment: @YoussifSaeed, I'm not getting any error. When calling the method to scan BT devices around it simply stays there searching until it reaches the timeout and without retrieving anything.

Comment: I’d suggest opening an issue with the plug-in asking for guidance